# Error in Vba when I try to save a ppt file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am beginner in coding and I am trying to write a code for save a ppt file into a pdf. However, I receive the msg "Run time error 424" Object Required", how can I fix?

There is my code:

```
Sub AbrirPP()

Dim ppPres As Object
Set ppPres = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

With ppPres  
    .Visible = True
    .Presentations.Open "C:\Users\Fede\Documents\Prueba.pptx"
    .ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks

    With ActivePresentation
        .SaveCopyAs _
            Filename:=.Path & "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".pdf", _
            FileFormat:=ppSaveAsPDF
    End With
End With

Set ppPre = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: make it  `With .ActivePresentation`  and 
   ` .SaveCopyAs Filename:=.Path & "\" & .Name & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".pdf", FileFormat:=ppSaveAsPDF` it will run

Comment: Thank You! Now I have an other error that it said "Run time Error" 2147024809 (80070057)" "Presentation.SaveCopyAs : Invalid Enumeration Value

Comment: Do you know what does it means?

Comment: Also it is always better to add a reference to “Microsoft “PowerPoint Application Objects library”.  It will help you writing code with dropdown.  Also make `Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Application`. otherwise make ppSaveasPdf  as its  Enumeration Value ie. 32